# WinForm Charts as a data grid column in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

I am trying to embed a winform chart in a WPF Data Grid using XAML.

XAML for the Data Grid is as follows:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ResultsDataGrid" MouseDoubleClick="ResultsDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Whisker Chart"  IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host">
                        <winformchart:Chart x:Name="test">
                            <winformchart:Chart.Series>
                                <winformchart:Series Name="series" ChartType="BoxPlot"/>
                            </winformchart:Chart.Series>
                            <winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
                                <winformchart:ChartArea/>
                            </winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
                        </winformchart:Chart>
                    </WindowsFormsHost>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How do I update the chart for every row?
Since each row will have its own chart, how can i dynamic assign a name to the chart.

Thanks.

Comment: Your posted XAML should include all namespaces you're using with it.

Comment: how are you adding rows?